# AWS S3 / Javascript callback issue

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3, callback

So, I'm having a problem with JavaScript asynchronous execution when making an API call to AWS S3.

I have a sequence of nested callbacks that are working fine up until a specific S3 call that my code is not waiting for. Here's my code:

```
getThumbUrls(contentIndex, function(data) {
  console.log('Returning from getThumbUrls');
  // let's just display thumbUrls[0] for now...
  console.log('The thumbUrls are ' + data[0]);
});
```

`getThumbUrls()` looks like this:

```
function getThumbUrls(contentIndex, callback) {
  console.log('Entering getThumbUrls');

  var thumbUrls = [];

  JSON.parse(contentIndex).forEach(videoKey => {
    // get the thumbnail: bucket-name/thumbnails/<first-key>
    console.log('videoKey = ' + videoKey);

    getThumbFileName(videoKey, function(thumbFileName) {
      console.log('Returning from getThumbFileName');
      console.log('Returned thumb filename is ' + thumbFileName);

      thumbUrls.push(CLOUDFRONT_URL + videoKey + '/thumbnails/' + thumbFileName);

    });

  });

  callback(thumbUrls);
}
```

And `getThumbFileName()` looks like this:

```
function getThumbFileName(videoKey, callback) {
  console.log('Entering getThumbFileName...');

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
    }
  });

  // Get the name of the file.
  params = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: videoKey + '/' + THUMBS_FOLDER,
    MaxKeys: 1
  };

  var urlKey;
  //console.log('listObjects params = ' + JSON.stringify(params, null, 4));
  s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      callback(err);
      return;
    }

    var thumbsKey = data.Contents;
    // MaxKeys was 1 bc first thumbnail key is good enough for now. Therefore, only one iteration.
    thumbsKey.forEach(function (keys) {
      console.log('thumbKey = ' + keys.Key);
      urlKey = keys.Key;
    });

  });

  callback(urlKey);
  //callback('20161111-TheWind.jpg');
}
```

Obviously, what's happening is that execution doesn't wait for the `s3.listObjectsV2` call to finish. I've verified that the entire flow works properly when all `getThumbFileName()` does is callback with the filename.

Would someone kindly show me how to force execution to wait for `s3.listObjectsV2` to complete before calling back with undefined?

Comment: using callbacks with forEach (and any type of iteration) is kinda complicated, why don't you use a promise approach? promises are meant to make our lives easier =)

Comment: I'm almost certain you are correct @guijob... that callbacks are complicating my life here. :) But I'm uncertain as to how to introduce promises here. Would you mind giving me a tip??? :D

Comment: I am currently reading about promises [here](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)... seeing as my approach indulges the "callback hell" anti-pattern. haha.. whoops.

Comment: I wrote a response to try help you out how starting using promises into your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, you should avoid callbacks approach when dealing with asynchronous operations over iterations, due their difficulty.

---

(You can skip this section if you don't want to know motivation behind promises approach).

Just to mention, in a callback approach, you must have to wait for all callbacks to complete in your `getThumbUrls()`, using a `if` which will check if all callbacks has been called, then just call `callback(thumbUrls);` with all responses pushed into your `thumbUrls` array:

```
function getThumbUrls(contentIndex, callback) {
  const thumbUrls = [];

  // counter which will increment by one for every callback
  let counter = 0;
  JSON.parse(contentIndex).forEach(videoKey => {
    getThumbFileName(videoKey, function (thumbFileName) {
      thumbUrls.push(CLOUDFRONT_URL + videoKey + '/thumbnails/' + thumbFileName);

      // for each callback response you must add 1 to a counter and then
      counter++;
      // check if all callbacks already has been called
      if (counter === JSON.parse(contentIndex).length) {
        // right here, thumbsUrls are filled with all responses
        callback(thumbUrls);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

---

So, you can make use of Promises, and a `Promise.all` will be enough for you to handle all responses from api. You can study over internet and check your code below, which is using a promise approach. I've added some comments to help you understanding what is happening.

```
// when using promises, no callbacks is needed
getThumbUrls(contentIndex)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Returning from getThumbUrls');
    // let's just display thumbUrls[0] for now...
    console.log('The thumbUrls are ' + data[0]);

  })

// when using promises, no callbacks is needed
function getThumbUrls(contentIndex) {
  console.log('Entering getThumbUrls');

  // not needed anymore, Promise.all will return all values
  // var thumbUrls = [];

  // Promise.all receives an array of promises and returns to next .then() all results
  // changing forEach to map to return promises to my Promise.all
  return Promise.all(JSON.parse(contentIndex).map(videoKey => {
    console.log('videoKey = ' + videoKey);

    // returning a promise
    return getThumbFileName(videoKey)
      .then(function (thumbFileName) {
        console.log('Returning from getThumbFileName');
        console.log('Returned thumb filename is ' + thumbFileName);

        return CLOUDFRONT_URL + videoKey + '/thumbnails/' + thumbFileName;
      });
  }))
}

// when using promises, no callbacks is needed
function getThumbFileName(videoKey) {
  console.log('Entering getThumbFileName...');

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
    }
  });

  // Get the name of the file.
  params = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: videoKey + '/' + THUMBS_FOLDER,
    MaxKeys: 1
  };

  // urlKey not need anymore
  // var urlKey;

  // most of AWS functions has a .promise() method which returns a promise instead calling callback funcions
  return s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise()
    .then(function (data) {
      var thumbsKey = data.Contents;
      //if you want to return only first one thumbsKey:
      return thumbsKey[0];
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      callback(err);
      return;
    })
}
```

Hope this helps you out in your study.

Comment: It helps me out tremendously. Not only in understanding where and why I was going wrong in my "callback hell" approach, but also helps my developing understanding of using promises. Thanks!! Your callback tip worked beautifully. Next, I'm going to reimplement using promises. I'll report back on how it goes. May take me a day.

Comment: Well, I'm VERY excited by what I've learned about Promises; even more so because I started with the terrible nested callback approach. Your solution using promises works perfectly; only issue is that `s3.listObjectsV2` needs to return `thumbsKey[0].Key`. Also, my `getThumbFileName` returns more than just the filename: it returns the prefix plus the thumbnail filename. So, that's been modified as well. You're a super teacher @guijob. Thank you! I'm going to keep writing promises now :)

Comment: Cool! That's part of js learning curve, once you get confident using `Promises` then you can learn about `async/await` keywords, which uses Promises and will make your async code readability much better

Answer (score 1):

> Would someone kindly show me how to force execution to wait

That's the wrong question.  You are not trying to get execution to "wait," or, at least, you shouldn't be.  You just need to call the callback in the right place -- inside the callback from `s3.listObjectsV2()`, not outside.

```
function getThumbFileName(videoKey, callback) {
  ...
  s3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      ...
    }

    var thumbsKey = data.Contents;
    // MaxKeys was 1 bc first thumbnail key is good enough for now. Therefore, only one iteration.
    thumbsKey.forEach(function (keys) {
      console.log('thumbKey = ' + keys.Key);
      urlKey = keys.Key;
    });

    callback(urlKey); // right
  });

  // wrong // callback(urlKey);

}
```

The way you wrote it, the callback fires after `s3.getObjectsV2()` **begins** to run -- not after it **finishes** (calls its own callback).

Comment: Thanks @michael-sqlbot. Unfortunately, the execution remains out of order... though I'm sure you're correct that my callback was in the wrong location given what I want to have happen. My issue is that I'm getting conceptually confused now as to how to have orderly returns from these callbacks.

Comment: Part of what you may be missing is that you don't want to have *"returns"* at all. That isn't how this is all supposed to work.  What a function with a callback actually *returns* ... is discarded.  Sprinkling some additional `console.log('...');` in your code should help clarify what happens, when.

Comment: You are right, of course. But I meant to refer to not _what_ it returns, but _when_ it returns. Currently, the call to `s3.listObjectsV2` is not completing before the enclosing callback. I've actually removed a ton of console.logs as I verified that everything was working prior to including that `s3.listObjectsV2` call. So, I feel I just need to _not return_ until it finishes. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but "not return until" is not your objective.  getThumbUrls should not actually be calling its callback... it actually needs to pass that callback to the next function, which calls it when done.  This is why it's called "callback hell."  For-Each is particularly messy because when you're working async with callbacks, there is no "not return until" -- that's not an option.

Comment: Okay. Clearly, I need to switch to promise / then / then / catch. I am investigating. Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Yes, that will make your life easier once you get the hang of it.